Azure AI Search Custom Skill, unable to keep the authResourceId in a skillset
I try to access an Azure Function which is protected by Microsoft Entra ID from an Azure AI Search Custom Web Skill. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-configuration
According to the document, I can access the function with the authResourceId, but it disappears after saving a skillset on Azure Portal. And of course, a request to the function fails due to the authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api
My skill definition right after saving on the portal. There is no error message while saving.

Then reopen the same skillset. The authResourceId has gone. It happens after saving edited a skill setting on a debug session too.

Both the AI Search Indexer and the Azure Function work great if I disable the Entra ID authentication stuff.
===EDIT===
I tried to make a skillset by REST API via REST Client extension of VS Code, but the authResourceId didn't persist either. This is the request. I omitted some parts for simplicity.
@endpoint=https://XXXX.search.windows.net

POST {{endpoint}}/skillsets?api-version=2023-10-01-Preview
    Content-type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{
  "name": "test04-index-custom-skillset",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "custom-embeding-skill",
      "description": "Custom-Skill-AzureFunctions",
      "context": "/document/pages/*",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/pages/*",
          "inputs": []
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "vector",
          "targetName": "text_vector"
        }
      ],
      "authResourceId": "api://appKey",
      "uri": "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/vectorize",
      "httpHeaders": {},
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1000
    }
  ],
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "test02-custom-skill-index",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "contentVector",
            "source": "/document/pages/*/text_vector"
          }
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  }
}

And the response is.
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; charset=utf-8
ETag: "0x8DD02DF818256FB"
Location: https://XXXX.search.windows.net:443/skillsets('test04-index-custom-skillset')?api-version=2023-10-01-Preview
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000, max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
Preference-Applied: odata.include-annotations="*"
OData-Version: 4.0
request-id: b4b1880e-7391-4e3a-8e6f-736d1279458e
elapsed-time: 75
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2024 06:01:53 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "@odata.context": "https://XXXX.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "name": "test04-index-custom-skillset",
  "description": null,
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "custom-embeding-skill",
      "description": "Custom-Skill-AzureFunctions",
      "context": "/document/pages/*",
      "uri": "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/vectorize",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1000,
      "degreeOfParallelism": null,
      "authResourceId": "api://appKey",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/pages/*",
          "sourceContext": null,
          "inputs": []
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "vector",
          "targetName": "text_vector"
        }
      ],
      "httpHeaders": {},
      "authIdentity": null
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "test02-custom-skill-index",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "contentVector",
            "source": "/document/pages/*/text_vector",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}

The authResourceId was there, but when I check it on the portal, it's gone.


what type of azure function you are looking for?

@Sampath I'm guessing you are asking a type of trigger, is that right? My function is http trigger.

did you configured managed identity in your search service.

@JayashankarGS Yes, the managed identity of the AI Search is on. The problem is that the authResourceId disappears after saving the skillset

Have you given permission to that identity in function app

@JayashankarGS Which permission? The document doesn't mention giving a permission to the managed identity as far as I know.

if you are providing identity app id in skillset then you need to add that in authentication provider in function app.

@JayashankarGS I don't get what you mean. I followed this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-configuration and put the function's application Id of Entra ID to the authResourceId in the skillset. There is no permission stuff you mentioned in the document. Moreover, what I'm facing is disappearing the authResourceId while saving a skillset.

Huh? Why down voted?

The permissions are mentioned in the managed-identity documentation (that has to be followed for any integration with managed-identity for AI Search indexers): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-managed-identities-data-sources. We've requested our docs expert to add a note also somewhere in the skill, since even if we make reference to this document from custom skills (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api), it looks like it's not discoverable/where you are looking and that they need clarification about the role.

@GiaMondragon-MSFT you misunderstood about the permission. You are talking about the ones for the mangaed identity of the AI Search. Of course I gave them to the managed identity like Contributor or such, I don't remember exlactly. What JayashankarGS mentioned was that setting permissions to the managed identity in the function app. But that one doesn't mention anywhere as far as I know

According to the documentation to use authResourceId parameter you need to call API with api-version=2023-10-01-Preview.
Same thing i got, after saving the skillset it is not visible when i refreshed. but you update the skillset using REST API with version 2023-10-01-Preview
Below is the sample i tested.

Next, it won't be visible in portal that is possibly due to the Api version used by portal to configure the search service.
You list the skillset using the rest Api itself you will the correct configuration.

Now you try to run indexer it will work, make sure you configured all the things properly when adding identity provider as per this documentation.

Does your index work with the Entra ID authentication enabled?

i haven't tried that. After you update skillset using above method you try.

Before you posted the answer, I already updated the skillset with the REST API as I edited my post yesterday, and tried running my indexer but it failed due to unauthorized. Can you try it to check whether the document is correct or not?

try giving the client id not app key  in this format /.default. also check if you missed anything while configuring Entra ID authentication.

You mean the clientid is the function's Entra ID of Application ID, right? Not the AI Search one.

yeah. whichever you added while configuring entra id auth. not the ai search one.

I tried running my indexer with /.default, but the result was the same "Unauthorized". Anyway, thank you for your help. Disappearing the authResourceId is kind of solved, so I'll close this question, and open a new one for the authentication of Azure Functions

Just raise new question with adding the details you followed in the documentation. don't delete this question.
